# Sending HTTP error with captureError from Angular shows error.custom.<name> in Kibana

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, kibana, apm

**Kibana version** : 7.6.2

**Elasticsearch version** : 7.6.2

**APM Server version** : 7.6.2

**APM Agent language and version** : `@elastic/apm-rum-angular` 1.1.1. Angular 9.1.0

**Original install method** : Used the [Angular Integration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/master/angular-integration.html)  instructions

While trying to Query Kibana for HTTP status code error, I see that these `custom` fields are not indexed and thus not filterable. It's weird that these even show up as `custom` at all, I would imagine that Elastic should know that these are HTTP errors and would match it accordingly to a field in Kibana.

See image, note `error.custom.<name>` (why are these being created?):

[image]

This is how I'm sending the error from Angular:

```
constructor(@Inject(ApmService) service: ApmService) {
    this.apmService = service.init({
      serviceName: 'frontend',
      serverUrl: 'http://localhost:8200/',
      serviceVersion: '1.0.0',
    });

    this.apmService.setUserContext({
      username: 'John',
      id: '001',
    });
  }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        let errorMessage = '';
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          // client-side error
          errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
        } else {
          // server-side error
          errorMessage = `Error: ${error.status} - ${error.message}`;
        }
        this.apmService.captureError(error, { response: error.status });
        return throwError(errorMessage);
      })
    );
  }
```

How do I send this error to APM so that Kibana correctly knows to fill this in with the correct fields it has?

Comment: I've been receiving the same error.